# SQL Error ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add row information to my table using INSERT INTO and I keep getting 
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 
Here is what I'm trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO cp2850Tutor
VALUES (100,'05-JAN-2008',Active);
```

I've tried putting quotes around Active and that gets a different error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: That column looks like its a number. You need to put a number in it. That's what the message is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to explicitly state the columns that you are inserting into

E.g
Insert into cp2850Tutor (IQ, JOINED_DATE, STATUS) 
Values (100,'05-JAN-2008', 1);

If you show us your DDL more help is possible

Answer (score 0):

if any constraint is applied to the columns, check for symantec errors
eg: if the column datatype is varchar2
    but the constraint applied is  : 
    check ( clm_name >  3 ) -- wrong one
    check ( length( clm_name) > 3 ) -- correct one